# Rails include through Jbuilder partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, associations, jbuilder

I have a jbuilder *show* that renders a partial:

`json.contents    @item_trackers, partial: 'item_trackers/item_tracker', as: :it`

In this partial I access my *pages_trackers* association through the *it* variable:

`json.pages       it.pages_trackers.order("created_at ASC")`

**The problem** is that when the request is fired, it loads every *page_tracker* that belongs to an *item_tracker* (one request for each).

**I've tried** to include the *pages_trackers* model in my controller:
`item_trackers.includes([:pages_trackers])`

But it still loads every *page_tracker* and I have the "unused eager loading" message:

Unused Eager Loading detected
ItemTracker => [:pages_trackers]
  Remove from your finder: :includes => [:pages_trackers]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was:
When I was calling the *order* method in the partial, it forced the requests to be fired again.
So I changed the SQL method *order* for the Ruby counterpart: `sort_by(&:created_at)`